# How does c# compiler handle addition and multiplication differently

Tags: c#, types

Since float/double numbers in c# can only be represented precisely if they are expressible in base 2; I would expect both `t2` and `t3` are non-zero but `t2 = 0` while t3 is indeed not zero. Can someone explain?

```
double d2 = 1.0/3.0;
double t2 = 1.0 - 3.0*d2;
double t3 = 1.0 - d2 - d2 - d2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `t2` you create several intermediate values that do indeed result in some amount of error.  It just so happens that the operations result in equal and opposite amounts of error, resulting in those errors coincidentally cancelling out to a *net* error of zero, and creating the correct result.

The case of `t3` results in the error of each of the intermediate operations being equal and not opposite, resulting in the errors compounding each other, rather than cancelling each other out, resulting in a net non-zero error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! Just tested and I think you're absolutely right as if I do  `1.0 - 2.0*d2 - d2` then it's not 0 which proves your point (at least to some extent).

Comment: so is this error cancellation random? I vaguely remember reading somewhere saying Microsoft has 'made' this cancellation on purpose in a way that at least most of time the result works just like normal algebra.

Comment: It's arbitrary, but not random.  You'll get the same result every time you do the operation (it's deterministic), but it's not by design.  You cannot rely on the fact that dividing by a number and then multiplying by the same number will result in the original value, in the general case.  You can expect them to be within a certain margin of error; in this case the error happens to be 0, but in the general case it's within a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the C# it self, but the way microprocessors work. You cant divide 1/3 and expect a number to be stored as 1/3.

The computer also do some tricks (add error) to make sense of common math:

```
double d1 = 1/3.0;
d1 = d1 * 3.0;
```

will result in

```
 d1 = 1.0
```

Comment: You don't explain **why** `d1 * 3.0` is equal to `1`.  Precisely because of the fact that the floating point number can't represent `1/3` exactly, you don't have any particularly reason to actually expect a result of `1`.